# Error compiling android with Lime/OpenFL. Unable to get Java version (Windows 10)

Tags: android, haxe, openfl

I get this at the end of my build:

```
Unzipping C:\Users\jdoughty\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-bin\2v0chm5oshw52qn5d7jjz7lo0\gradle-2.10-bin.zip to C:\Users\jdoughty\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-bin\2v0chm5oshw52qn5d7jjz7lo0

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Build halted with errors.
```

This confuses me slightly because it seems like it has the version... but that's my primitive understanding of what's going on.

This is the contents of my `.lime/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>

    <section id="defines">


    </section>
    <define name="ANDROID_NDK_ROOT" value="C:\android-ndk-r15c-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r15c" />
    <define name="ANDROID_SDK" value="C:\Users\jdoughty\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" />
    <define name="JAVA_HOME" value='"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1"' />
    <define name="ANDROID_SETUP" value="true" />

</config>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the Android SDK support doesn't support Java 10 (or 9) just yet - try downgrading to Java 8.

There's reports of a similar issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17688